# PHP - execute function or exit form based on PHP statement evaluation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have php statement evaluation in my page I want to execute the PHP function **updatePaidStatus();** when the user confirmed or exit the form if the user cancels the confirmation.

here is the code:

```
if($Exp_Total>0 && $Rem_Total>0)
{
    //for example I want to do like this using javascript

echo '<script> if {Confirmed --> then call this function-->updatePaidStatus();}

else {Cancelled confirmation-->exit the form}
</script>';
}
```